# Gnuplot unrecognized command 0x9

Tags: gnuplot

I need to plot data in a .dat document with gnuplot. Data I'm trying to plot is represented in a file outfile.dat like this (a little sample):

```
0.900   500.000 100.000
1.900   500.000 100.000
2.900   500.000 100.000
3.900   500.000 100.000
4.900   500.000 100.000
5.900   500.000 100.000
6.900   500.000 100.000
7.900   500.000 100.000
8.900   500.000 100.000
9.900   500.000 100.000
10.900  500.000 100.000
```

As you can see, there is a tab character separating every column. There isn't rare character at all. When I try to plot this file with

```
plot "outfile.dat" using 1:2
```

I get the following error:

```
libplot error: flinewidth: invalid operation
plot: an unrecognized command `0x9' was encountered in the input
plot: the input file `salida.dat' could not be parsed
```

Why I'm getting this error? What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Which gnuplot version are you using?

Comment: Version 2.6 in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Weird, "tab" should be understood by gnuplot. Is your file complete? Is any value missing? Is it too long to be posted online?

Comment: There are approx. 1000 lines but I've just check it and it's complete... Anyway it must be working with the little sample I've posted, right?

Comment: This example works fine on my computer.

Comment: Wait a minute. Gnuplot `2.6`???

Comment: debug your file.  try to gnuplot 10 lines, then 20, etc.  find where do you have the problem.

Comment: gnuplot 4.0 was released 13 years ago.

Comment: Yes... If I execute `plot --version` says `plot (GNU plotutils) 2.6`

Comment: Wait. plotutils and gnuplot aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

I think I got it.

You're not using gnuplot, you're using [plotutils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/plotutils).

You first need to launch gnuplot in your terminal, with `gnuplot`. You can then launch `plot "outfile.dat" using 1:2` inside gnuplot, **not** your terminal.

Comment: Where I should put this command? In terminal this doesn't work: `plot "outfile.dat" using 1:2 set datafile separator "\t"`